# Best way to convert Dictionary<string, string> into single aggregate String representation?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, aggregate

How would I convert a dictionary of key value pairs into a single string? Can you do this using LINQ aggregates? I've seen examples on doing this using a list of strings, but not a dictionary.

**Input:**

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
          {"A", "Alpha"},  
          {"B", "Beta"}, 
          {"G", "Gamma"}
};
```

**Output:**

```
  string result = "A:Alpha, B:Beta, G:Gamma";
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is the most concise way I can think of:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", map.Select(m => m.Key + ":" + m.Value).ToArray());
```

If you are using .NET 4+ you can drop the `.ToArray()`:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", map.Select(m => m.Key + ":" + m.Value));
```

And if you are able to use the newish string interpolation language feature:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", map.Select(m => $"{m.Key}:{m.Value}"));
```

However, depending on your circumstances, this might be faster (although not very elegant):

```
var result = map.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
    (a, b) => a.Append(", ").Append(b.Key).Append(":").Append(b.Value),
    (a) => a.Remove(0, 2).ToString());
```

I ran each of the above with a varying number of iterations (10,000; 1,000,000; 10,000,000) on your three-item dictionary and on my laptop, the latter was on average 39% faster. On a dictionary with 10 elements, the latter was only about 22% faster.

One other thing to note, simple string concatenation in my first example was about 38% faster than the `string.Format()` variation in [mccow002's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8002384/74757), as I suspect it's throwing in a little string builder in place of the concatenation, given the nearly identical performance metrics.

To recreate the original dictionary from the result string, you could do something like this:

```
var map = result.Split(',')
    .Select(p => p.Trim().Split(':'))
    .ToDictionary(p => p[0], p => p[1]);
```

Comment: Didn't see yours before I posted mine. +1 for brilliant thinking :)

Comment: how can I back from these var result to original dictionary?

Comment: @zipi: Edited the question to include a quick way to get back to the original dictionary.

Answer (score 8):

```
string result = string.Join(", ", map.Select(x => string.Format("{0}:{1}", x.Key, x.Value)).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 3):

This uses [LINQ Aggregate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
map
.Select(m => $"{m.Key}:{m.Value}")
.Aggregate((m1, m2) => $"{m1}, {m2}");
```

Same but with `string.Format()`:

```
map
.Select(m => string.Format("{0}:{1}", m.Key, m.Value))
.Aggregate((m1, m2) => string.Format("{0}, {1}", m1, m2))
```