# How do I pass a dictionary as a parameter when I don't care about a dictionary's types?

Tags: c#, dictionary, stringify

Similar to this question:

[Best way to convert Dictionary<string, string> into single aggregate String representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002340/best-way-to-convert-dictionarystring-string-into-single-aggregate-string-repr)

But I want to ignore the types in the Dictionary, since I plan on calling the ToString() method of each key and value.

I think it should not be a problem, but I cannot figure out how to pass in an untyped dictionary, short of just casting it as Object... any ideas?

[EDIT] Add working code snippet:
This works - thanks twoflower

```
public string DumpDictionary<TKey, TElement>(IDictionary<TKey, TElement> dictionary)
{
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (var v in dictionary)
      {
           sb.AppendLine(v.Key.ToString() + ":" + v.Value.ToString());
      }
      return sb.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: You can try passing it as `IDictionary` but I'm not sure that will work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about just

```
void DumpDictionary<TKey, TElement>(IDictionary<TKey, TElement> dictionary)
{
   ...
}
```

You can then call this without the type arguments since they will be inferred (in most cases):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<long, MyClass>();
...
DumpDictionary(dictionary);
```