# converting list of dictionaries to string and vice-versa

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a list of dictionaries as List< Dictionary< String,int>> which I have to convert to string and then convert back to the same format List< Dictionary< String,int>>. I tried using

```
string ratio = string.Join("$", order);
```

It converts to string but I am unable to retrieve the dictionary back from string value using but it gives an error that it cannot convert from string[] to dictionary.

```
List<String> convertStringToList = new List<Dictionary<String,String>(ratios.Split('$'));
```

Comment: try my solution given below thanks.

Comment: I believe relying on magic strings like $ or anything like that would NOT help. Why not use a simple serializer to xml which would return a plain xml string which you can deserialize to object later.

Comment: can you tell me how to serialize List<Dictionary>. i have done serializing List<String> but method crashed on using dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most concise way I can think of:

**Updated Start**

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> convertStringToList= new   List<Dictionary<string, string>>()
List<string> strList = new List<string>();
Foreach(var dic in convertStringToList)
{
  string result = string.Join(", ", dic.Select(m => m.Key + ":" + m.Value).ToArray());
  strList.add(result);
}
```

**Updated End**

However, depending on your circumstances, this might be faster (although not very elegant):

```
Foreach(var dic in convertStringToList)
    {
      string result = dic.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
        (a, b) => a.Append(", ").Append(b.Key).Append(":").Append(b.Value),
        (a) => a.Remove(0, 2).ToString());
      strList.add(result);
    }
```

**[Reference:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002340/best-way-to-convert-dictionarystring-string-into-single-aggregate-string-repr)**

Hope it Helps.

Comment: the first line is giving the error : cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>'

Comment: did you go through the given reference? and updated solution

Comment: thanks again but you are converting the dictionary to string whereas I have a list of dictionaries.

Comment: @apurv now check my updated code between **Updated Start** And **Updated End** .

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below snippet.

```
string ratio = string.Join("$", data);

var convertStringToList  = ratio.Split(new[] {'$'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(part => part.Split(','))
            .ToDictionary(split => split[0].Trim('['), split => split[1].Trim(']'));
```

Comment: okay thanks, the above method gives me the list but I am still unable to get the dictionaries

Comment: @apurv It should returns you the type Dictionary<string,string>. bcoz in last statement we are casting it to dictionary  using "ToDictionary".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend @Zaheer 's answer, but if you can't change the code, you can use the code:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(string.Join("$", dict).Split('$')
     .Select(x => 
          new KeyValuePair<String, String>(
              x.Substring(1, x.IndexOf(',')),
              x.Substring(x.IndexOf(',')+1, x.Length-x.IndexOf(',')-2))));
```

The format of `string.Join('$', order)` will be `[key, value]$[key, value].....`